# Swagger UI throwing 403 when implemented JWT authentication

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a Swagger UI plugin added to my code base. It was running fine until I add the JWT authentication. I can just apply `.permitAll()` , but I don't want everyone to have access to my Swagger Page. Below is my Swagger config

```
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringFoxConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        logger.info("Starting Swagger");
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .forCodeGeneration(true)
                .enableUrlTemplating(true)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.***.controllers"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo());
    }
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I want to be getting page asking for auth header JWT, but it is throwing a 403 forbidden error.

This is from my Security Config file:
`.antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-resources/**", "/webjars/**", "/v2/**").permitAll()`

Does anyone have a recommendation for me to try? I want Swagger to ask for JWT token when I open it.